# How to send arguments into transform function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create following function:

```
mysplit_col <- function(df, colname, sepstr=':', 
                       firstname='part1', secondname='part2'){
    df_split<- strsplit(as.character(df[,colname]), split=sepstr)
    transform(df, firstname= sapply(df_split, "[[", 1),secondname= sapply(df_split, "[[", 2))
}

> mydf
  name position
1  HLA   1:1-15
2  HLA   1:2-16
3  HLA   1:3-17

> dput(mydf)
structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "HLA", class = "factor"), 
    position = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1:1-15", "1:2-16", 
    "1:3-17"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("name", "position"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))

> mysplit_col_(mydf, 'position')
  name position firstname secondname
1  HLA   1:1-15         1       1-15
2  HLA   1:2-16         1       2-16
3  HLA   1:3-17         1       3-17
```

But in output new columns are named 'firstname' and 'secondname' and not 'part1' and 'part2'

Example data is from: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6806/splitting-a-numeric-column-for-a-dataframe

How can I correct this problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, just don't use `transform`. It's intended for interactive use. `df[, firstname] <- ...`

Comment: How trivial. Thanks very much.